# Rearranged columns in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I get the rearranged columns out of a datagridview in C#? I need to get all the columns currently being displayed in order. I can get the default columns order by setting `datagridview.AutoGenerateColumns=false` but I get the same old order even after I've rearranged the columns in my table.

Edit: Basically what I need is to be able to iterate through all the columns of a datagridview based on their display index

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [DisplayIndex property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex.aspx) of your DataGridView Columns.

The DisplayIndex property:

> Gets or sets the display order of the
>   column relative to the currently
>   displayed columns.

**Edit:**
It's ugly, and I'm sure people are going to point and laugh, but this might give you a rough idea on one implementation to improve upon.

Create a DGV with three columns and set their DisplayName properties like so:

```
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 1;
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].DisplayIndex = 2;
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].DisplayIndex = 0;
```

Add the following code to loop through all the columns access the columns in the DGV in their DisplayIndex order:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; index++) {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns) {
            if (c.DisplayIndex == index) {
                // You've got your next column.
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok. But how can I iterate through all the columns based on the display index property?

Comment: Could optimize it slightly by breaking once you've found the next column.

Comment: I'm also thinking something similar to yours 'rough' solutions but it looks that we will skip some columns if we implemented this way.

Comment: This way should be ok. If you want other suggestions you could keep a dictionary<int,int> of the display index as the key, and the actual index as the value, then you iterate over the keys and use dataGridView1.Columns[value] to go in display order (since value would give you the actual index for the display index)

Answer (score 0):

How are you selecting? SELECT *? You need to specify the columns in the order you want them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you rearranged their order in the ItemTemplate section of your grid? You can also change the order via the context menu for a GridView, alternative you can change your SQL statement and make sure autogenerate is off